# Using common class for anchor tag to perform the same function in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I open a popup form on my site a hash is added to the URL e.g. #contact. I would like the close button and a click off of the form to remove the #contact hash.

I am currently using code that can achieve this for a single ID (anchor tag) but I would like to extend the functionality to multiple anchor tags by using a common class. The code I am using is as follows:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('closeForm');
btn.disabled = !(location.hash || location.href.slice(-1) == "#"); 
btn.onclick = removeHash;
window.onhashchange = function () { 
    btn.disabled = !(location.hash || location.href.slice(-1) == "#");     
}
function removeHash() { 
    window.history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);
    btn.disabled = !(location.hash || location.href.slice(-1) == "#");     
}
```

I have tried substituting `getElementById` for `GetElementsByClassName` to create my variable but it does not work.

I could achieve the results that I want by rewriting my code snippet three times and changing the variables and listing additional Id's but this seems tremendously redundant.

Comment: Please show how you implemented it. Were errors thrown?

Comment: @charlietfl Basically I substituted getElementById with getElementsByClassName and changed the class names of the desired anchor tags. No errors were thrown although I'm not testing on a live server.

Comment: well `getElementsByClassName ` doesn't return a single element like `getElementById` it returns an element collection

Comment: just be careful with the `HTMLCollection` returned by `getElementsByClassName` as this is a "live" list, so can have unexpected side effects